# is it possible to install a linux distro in an unmounted partition without a bootable device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, system-installation

Maybe the question is stupid, but I haven't been able to find anything anywhere to confirm that.

I have 1TB HDD which has two ext4 partitions. In one partition, I've my main OS (Ubuntu). And another partition is empty.

I'd like to install an another OS in my second partition. Is it possible, while being in one partition (Ubuntu), to install an OS in another unmounted partition ( and finally update the grub menu ).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use grub to load an ISO and install. Just as simple as a USB.
There are many ways to do so, like `loopback` in grub command line.
If you mean installing directly from your ubuntu, it's also possible.
Use VirtualBox or VMware. But just select the partition as disk file. 
As to grub menu,  `update-grub` will automatically detect OSs and add boot entries for them.

Comment: I did not know that, thanks ! I will give it a check

Comment: I was able to find this article for your first point: https://www.howtogeek.com/196933/how-to-boot-linux-iso-images-directly-from-your-hard-drive/

Comment: The article is good and detailed. Yeah, many tutorials about grub are available.